# Laravel gets slow if ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, laravel

I have an issue with laravel 4.1. with ajax requests.
We have made restful api and when I do request from browser or postman everthing goes fine.

[image: Postman 543ms]

but when I do the same request from Angular or jquery it goes very very slow (about 20 seconds)

[image: Ajax 17.42s]

I cannot find why is this happening.

**My configuration**

- Windows 7
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.5.7
- PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Clockwork shows only 415ms so I think that the problem is somwhere in framework booting.

Comment: Can you post the related code? Do you handle the ajax requests differently?

Comment: The selected resource has only route, basecontroller and eloquent model nothing more. Standard and AJAX requests are handled absolutly same way in application. Because its API without any view, response is always JSON.

Comment: Have you tried it using other browsers?

Comment: Note that Clockwork's timeline also includes the framework booting time.

Comment: I have tried another browser but same results. Ok I see framework boot time in Clockwork and that looks fine. So where is the issue?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. Consider looking at the log files or trying it using other stacks.

Comment: I tested that in production environment and its the same. Production stack is based on linux and nginx. I don't have more details about the flow because clockwork is not enabled in there.